# Initial view controller on storyboard

Tags: xcode-storyboard

I had two view controllers and I deleted the one that had the Designated entry point. How do I get it back? I have tried creating a new controller but what I'm asking I think is much simpler.

Comment: Are you talking about on the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storyboard, each view controller has 3 buttons at the top. Click the left button, looking like a yellow circle with a white square inside.

[image]

Then in the attributes inspector you can check the option that says:

> Is Initial View Controller

[image]